# How to use non-italic units in Nomenclature?

Tags: siunitx, italic, nomenclature, units

I tried using the **siunitx** package and converting the units to non-italic for the units that appear in the Nomenclature section as below:

```
\nomenclature[a-av]{$a^v$}{Active specific surface area\nomunit{\si{$m^2/m^3$}}}
```

but it had no effect. Nut it works all good with the main body. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Er, I'm not sure at all what you are up to with units: `\si{m^{2}/m^{3}}` or `\si{\metre\squared\per\metre\cubed}`, (or with v3 use `\unit`).

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, this is part of my thesis and part of a very large document. I'll try to come up with a MWE.

Comment: I am trying to get the units without being in italics. In the main body of the text \si command works a charm, but not in the nomenclature..

Comment: @BuV8 But you simply shouldn't have `$` inside the unit argument, so there is more going on here - as mentioned, we need a MWE

Comment: Try replacing `\si{$m^2/m^3$}` with `\si[per-mode=symbol]{\meter\squared\per\meter\cubed}`. If you really can't be bothered with syntax niceties, try `\si{m^2/m^3}`.